# What's the purpose of @media (max-width:-1)

Tags: css

Looking at some CSS that another department designed and came across this media descriptor:

```
@media (max-width:-1) {
    ...standard css stuff here
}
```

Since you cannot have width < 0, what would the purpose be of this?  Maybe just some leftover CSS which was being tested?

In addition, also came across

```
@media (min-width:0) {
}
```

Which of course would always be active.

Comment: For when you fold the right edge over the left edge in them fancy foldable displays…?

Comment: the last one could be used to detect a mediaquery capable browser.

Comment: what not asking the other department?

Comment: I have no idea who wrote it (or when).  Company of >500 people.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@media (max-width:-1) {
    ...standard css stuff here
}
```

I believe this is invalid condition so it will never get executed

Answer (score 0):

```
@media (min-width:0) {
}
```

basically telling the browser that apply CSS only if the viewport is 0 pixels wide or wider(greater than or equal 0) **, in this case, all screen sizes**.

```
@media (max-width:-1) {
    ...standard CSS stuff here
}
```

Means screen width is between 0 and -1. As @Rahul said is an invalid condition.

Comment: So why have a media descriptor if it applies to all screen sizes?

Comment: This can be used to select a breakpoint between two screen sizes e.g.   `@media (min-width: 0) and (max-width: 568px)` which basically means screen width is between 0 and 568px.

Comment: I understand what the media descriptor is, but the value of 0 or -1 is the issue.